# Python's behavior at global variables assignment followed by exception

Tags: python, exception, global-variables

I'm writing a python function which runs a long-running computation. The computation needs careful debugging so my idea is to keep the state global to be able to review it in IPython. If it is important, the state is a TensorFlow model and the computation is its training. *(Correction 1: it is not actually important)* 
Of cause, if I see that training doesn't go well, I don't want to wait until it is complete and hit Ctrl+C in **IPython** hoping to review `M.model`, make some fixes and so on.

Unfortunately, if I ask **IPython** to print value of `M` after `KeyboardInterrupt` exception, I would see None! But how can it be? I'm pretty sure that training has already began, so `M=Model()` line should have been already executed.

*Correction 2: It turns out that it is important to load the file in IPython using `from test import *` syntax.*

---

MCVE:

```
# Instructions
# 0. Save this program to test.py file.
# 1. Load the file in IPython with `from test import *` syntax
# 2. call `run()`, wait for some short time.
# 3. Interrupt it with Ctrl+C
# 4. See no global state changed

from typing import Any,Optional
from time import sleep

class Model:
  state:Any

def train(m:Model)->None:
  m.state = 0
  print('Hit Ctrl+C to interrupt "training". Check out (the absence of) M.state')
  while True:
    m.state = m.state + 1
    print('.', end='', flush=True)
    sleep(1)

M:Optional[Model]=None

def run():
  global M
  M=Model()
  train(M)
```

Comment: Does `train` operate On or mutate `M` or does it just use `M` values?

Comment: It does mutate `M` by adding new fields. Here is how it looks like: https://gist.github.com/grwlf/bc845b597ceaf7b089cd25de9d3fbe30#file-train_assign-py-L104  Note, that this script contains a workaround I've managed to find. The question is still valid.

Comment: I need to say more clearly, that while `train` does mutate `M`, it never removes anything. A common pattern inside `train(m)` is `m.model.something = value`.

Comment: I reproduced the issue in a minimal example. TensorFlow details are not really important. https://gist.github.com/grwlf/467422ce50f1e6f298d77a8447496d38

Comment: Cannot reproduce:  put your mcve code in a module (tmp.py); imported tmp.py into iPython console; called `tmp.run`; after some seconds typed `ctrl-c`; verified `tmp.M.state`'s value equaled number of seconds elapsed.

Comment: Wow, my test procedure is a bit different! I usually import file in IPython with `from tmp import *` syntax (and later just do `run()`). I still see the issue if I use this method. But it works perfectly well if I use `import tmp`, followed with `tmp.run()`...  I think I should fix the question again :)